# race condition in logic for database

Tags: database, race-condition

I have a database server.

The application logic is that it will query to see if a particular row exist, if not, it will insert a new row. The query is done in Java and container managed transactions.

So with 2 application server running the same code, is it possible for both servers to check the row don't exist, and both insert the row. (the insert will be successful due to another unique auto-number primary key column)

how do we ensure there is only one and only one unique row for that data ?

sknaht

Comment: The way I like to handle this kind of thing is to create a UNIQUE constraint on the column you expect to be unique (or group of columns). Don't check for existence, just always attempt to insert the row with the specified data, and catch any exception (thrown by the database engine) in your business logic for that. That's the only real way to handle race conditions like this

Answer (score 1):

> the insert will be successful due to another unique auto-number primary key column

Most DBMSes offer a way to create a "unique key" or "unique index" that enforces uniqueness of a given column (or set of columns) even if it's not the primary key. The second insert would then fail, just as if it had violated a primary-key constraint.

You haven't indicated what DBMS you're using, but most (all?) of the common ones have this feature; for example, PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle all do.